# Wordpress Pod Relationshop field

Tags: wordpress, podscms

Is it possible to display a template for a related pod?

```
$mypod = pods('custompage', 'page-slug');
$related_pod = $mypod->field('top_feature');
```

Now I want to call something like

```
$related_pod->template('FeatureTemplate');
```

I can't seem to find a solid answer in this docs, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do will not work. The problem is that `$related_pod` is not an object of the Pods class, and therefore you can not call the method `template()` on it.

It is possible to use the ID of the related item to build a second Pods object for the related post, which we can then call the method `template()` on. Normally we wouldn't do this because we don't need to and its not the most performant way of working.

Here is how you can do this. IMPORTANT: this assumes that "top_feature" is a single select field, as it is in OP's case. This will not work for a multi-select field.

```

```
$mypod = pods( 'custompage', 'page-slug' );
$relationship_field = $mypod->field( 'top_feature' );

if ( $relationship_field ) {

    //get ID of related item
    //Depending on content type you may need to use, 'id', instead of 'ID'
    $related_item_id = pods_v( 'ID', $relationship_field );

    $related_pod = pods( 'name_of_related_pod', $related_item_id, true );
    if ( is_a( $related_pod, 'Pods' && $related_pod->id() === $id ) ) {
        $related_pod->template( 'FeatureTemplate' );

    }

}
```

```

Comment: It is a Single select, Thanks :)